# Create Rows and Tables using BeautifulSoup python with xml to json convertion

Tags: python, xml, csv

Currently I'm creating a parser script that can convert xml to json, my plan is to modify my script and add creation of rows and columns when I convert it to csv file.

The current output of my script it can only creates newlines.

My Script

```
xml_parser = BeautifulSoup(open('SAMPLE.xml'), 'xml')
DESCRIPTION = xml_parser.DESCRIPTION
NAME = xml_parser.NAME
LOCATION = xml_parser.LOCATION
STATUS = xml_parser.STATUS



data = {
        'DESCRIPTION' : DESCRIPTION.text,
        'NAME' : NAME.text,
        'LOCATION' : LOCATION.text,
        'STATUS' : STATUS.text,
        }

print(json.dumps(data).replace(",","\n"))
```

Output

```
DESCRIPTION: MAIN FLOOR
NAME: FORT-0232
LOCATION: MIDDLE
STATUS: ACTIVE
```

**Plan Output to be**

```
DESCRIPTION |   NAME    | LOCATION | STATUS |
MAIN FLOOR  | FORT-0232 |  MIDDLE  | ACTIVE |
```

Comment: Could you give an example of what you want the output to be?

Comment: Hi @Jortega, my plan is to have rows and columns it has header and below will be the data when I compile/convert it to csv like in my **Plan Output to be** is it possible to add/modify my current script right now?

Comment: So "xml to json convertion" is not accurate? It sounds like you are looking for json to a "string table".

Comment: Yes, I compile it using beautifulsoup and get only the data needed which is in my sample **OUTPUT** and replace "," and create newline is it possible to create rows and columns like my sample in **Plan Output to be** with my current script?